# What am i doing wrong here? Android context menu long click

Tags: android, menu, android-intent, contextmenu

I got my list view to respond to a long click. I override oncreatecontext menu

```
AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
Intent facebookbrowserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
            Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://autobotcentral.info/sd/&t=the_title"));
Intent twitterbrowserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
            Uri.parse("http://twitter.com/?status=the_title"));
menu.setHeaderTitle(mStrings.get(info.position).CleanName);

Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);         
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body",  mStrings.get(info.position).CleanName );

output.setText(mStrings.get(info.position).CleanName);

menu.addIntentOptions(Menu.NONE, 0, 0,
    this.getComponentName(),null, facebookbrowserIntent, 0, null);

menu.addIntentOptions(Menu.NONE, 0, 1,
        this.getComponentName(),null, sendIntent, 0, null);
menu.addIntentOptions(   Menu.NONE, 0, 2,
        this.getComponentName(),null, twitterbrowserIntent, 0, null);

menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, 0,   "Facebook Entry");
menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, 1, "Sms to friend");
menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, 2, "Twitter Entry");
```

However this is not exactly what shows up. Sometimes other words (that shouldn't even) show up. None of the intents fire correctly. I've fiddled with group and order. Not sure exactly of what the sparse docs meant. Any help?

Comment: messaging. Browser. The code is clean, compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a closer look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#addIntentOptions%28int,%20int,%20int,%20android.content.ComponentName,%20android.content.Intent%5B%5D,%20android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.view.MenuItem%5B%5D%29) for `addIntentOptions`. That method adds menu items. This means that when you do `addIntentOptions` it will create menu items. When you do `add` you'll create even more items. You don't need to do the `menu.Add` statements. This [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#intents) is probably a good guide for what you're trying to do.